# Is frequently switching between sandbox and production mode while working with PayPal API a bad practice?

Tags: laravel, paypal, paypal-sandbox

So I have a website that uses PayPal for making payments (and also some payouts). I first created a sandbox app and designed a solution which worked exactly. Then I switch to production and everything worked fine. Now the client has come up with some new requirements and it seems to modify, I have to switch back to sandbox.

So my question is that is frequently switching between PayPal environment modes a bad practice ?

One more thing for some reasons I cannot test this on my local machine.
Everything is happening live and on production server.

Comment: Are you suggesting that you are switching between sandbox and live PayPal on your production site?

Comment: @WilliamChong its more of site that is deployed on internet but still not indexed and not yet publicly spread.

Answer (score 0):

The good practice is:

If you are going to make changes, use the sandbox first and verify that everything is correct.

After that, you go to production.

Comment: Hey Thanks for the reply. As stated in my question I tested it on my sandbox and it worked fine. Then I switched to production then it worked fine too, now the thing is after a while (which include months) the client decided to change some flow, hence my question.

Comment: Yes, you must apply the same.

Remember that it is better to have a test environment first and then a production environment.

The risk you run in testing direct changes in production, no matter the exchange rate, is a high risk.